# How do I resolve a 0x80040e14 and 0xC0202071 in SSIS?

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2013, ssis, sql-server-2014

I am extremely new to SSIS and may need allot of things explained.

What I am trying or attempting to accomplish is this:

1. Connect to an XML site using SSIS in VS-2013
2. Delete the existing data in the table
3. Dump the parsed XML data to the table

I am getting the following execute errors in SSIS:

- [SQL Server Destination [61]] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80040E14. An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0"  Hresult: 0x80040E14  Description: "Could not bulk load because SSIS file mapping object 'Global\DTSQLIMPORT              ' could not be opened. Operating system error code 5(Access is denied.). Make sure you are accessing a local server via Windows security.".
- [SQL Server Destination [61]] Error: Unable to bulk copy data. You may need to run this package as an administrator.
- [SSIS.Pipeline] Error: SQL Server Destination failed the pre-execute phase and returned error code 0xC0202071.

I do not even know what information to add to be helpful. I have a data flow which consists of a XML web source and a destination that points to a SQL table on the system.

My Questions are:

1. How do I resolve the errors mentioned above?
2. What am I missing?

Comment: are you specifying login credentials or are you using integrated security with your connection string?

Comment: Specifying a SQL Server account

Comment: are you getting this error when you run this design mode or when the package runs in a job

Comment: If I change the account to integrated security I get a results table of what I am after and some more errors (0x80040E14, 0x80004005 and 0xC02020C7)
 -

Comment: I get the error when I manually run the task from visual studio. And I have also disabled UAC as well

Comment: sounds to me like a permissions issue because of the bulk copy. If I am not mistaken a bulk copy automatically disables triggers, primary and foreign key(someone correct me if i am wrong). This requires the use have alter permissions within the target database. This needs to be explicitly granted to the user.

Comment: OK... I reran the task as my user account and it actually ran. So what do I need to do to get this to work for a database user?

Comment: You need to make sure that the database user that you are specifying in the connection string has the necessary permissions for the tasks that need to be completed. I would assume that the user is going to need reader and writer permissions with the addition of alter permissions to the necessary schemas.

Comment: OK, Ive made the schema and role permission changes for reader, writer and alter and still no dice.

Comment: I wasnt saying that is all that you will need I was simply saying that was where I would start. The other option is to create that database user as a mirror to your own user credentials and see if the process works. If you set the user up with the exact permissions as your user then you can rule that out. This can be a dangerous way to go about it tho. you need to make sure that you do not grant any unnecessary administrator permissions

Comment: I think I have a solution. From what I was reading about this issue on just about everything I could find, this has something to do with elevated windows permissions (weird since this is a SQL Server account). So I removed the SQL Server destination and replaced it with an OLE DB destination. So far it appears to be working from VS 2013 but still fails from SQL Server Agent. According to the logs in SQL Server, it has to do with the Password. Don't understand why since it runs fine in VS 2013.

Comment: Can you post the error you get in the SQL Agent?  There are different security considerations when running in SQL Agent than in the design runtime in BIDS/SSDT.

Comment: Date  06/03/2015 12:32:26
Log  SQL Server (Current - 06/03/2015 12:03:00)

Source  Logon

Message
Login failed for user 'CorporateWebUser'. Reason: Password did not match that for the login provided. [CLIENT: <local machine>]

Comment: the part I do not understand is that it runs fine from VS

Comment: I found the solution or rather @SFrejofsky in the post below. After hard coding the password in the dtsx code, it now runs in both VS and SSMS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to set your connection string as an expression and either hard code or parametrize your user and password.

The password is encrypted based on information from the machine that it is encrypted on. Once you move that encrypted property to the server it will not know how to decrypt it and therefore does not have a valid password.

I had to do this with a project I was working on with AZURE. I believe there is a setting to remove the encryption from the password but that is no different then hard coding the user and pass in the connection string expression.